# Finding row wise sum of transpose of hv-convex binary matrix

Tags: graphs, combinatorics

I'm stuck on a problem involving the Gale-Ryser Theorem. The problem's input gives me the row-wise sum of an hv-convex binary matrix(n*m).

```
e.g. I get {4,3,2,2,1} in the input. It's the row wise sum of the following matrix:

    1 1 1 1
    1 1 1 0
    1 1 0 0
    1 1 0 0
    1 0 0 0
```

To solve the problem, I have to find the row-wise sum of it's transpose.

```
i.e. I need to calculate {5,4,2,1}

1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

Can it be achieved in less than O(n*m)?

Comment: In other words, you are looking for an algorithm that conjugates a partition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-increasing sequence of integers is known as a *partition*. The operation you are describing is known as *conjugation*. Given a partition $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n$, you can compute its conjugate $\lambda'_1,\ldots,\lambda'_m$ as follows:

- Initialize a pointer $i$ at $n$.
- Set $\lambda'_1 = i$.
- Advance $i$ backwards until $\lambda_i \geq 2$.
- Set $\lambda'_2 = i$.
- Advance $i$ backwards until $\lambda_i \geq 3$.
- Set $\lambda'_3 = i$.
- ...
- Stop once $i = 1$.

As an example, here is how you apply this algorithm on $4,3,2,2,1$.
$$
\begin{align*}
&\begin{array}{ccccc}
4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
&&&& \uparrow \\
&&&& 5
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{ccccc}
4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
&&& \uparrow \\
&&& 4
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{ccccc}
4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
& \uparrow \\
& 2
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{ccccc}
4 & 3 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
\uparrow \\
1
\end{array}
\end{align*}
$$
It might happen that at some point $i$ doesn't advance at all. This is what happens if we apply this algorithm on $5,4,2,1$:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
&&& \uparrow \\
&&& 4
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
&& \uparrow \\
&& 3
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
& \uparrow \\
& 2
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
& \uparrow \\
& 2
\end{array} \\\hline
&\begin{array}{cccc}
5 & 4 & 2 & 1 \\
\uparrow \\
1
\end{array}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Why did you stop at 4 twice in the second example?

Comment: Oh.. it's because it satisfied the condition for 3 as well as 4 right?

Comment: Right, this is why I included this example.

Answer (score 3):

The row-wise sum of the transpose is just the column-wise sum of the original matrix. So, for inputs $a_1 \cdots a_n$ and outputs $b_1 \cdots b_m$, it looks something like this:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c&c&c&lcr}
 & b_1=4 & b_2=2 & b_3=1 \\
\hline
a_1=3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
a_2=2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
a_3=1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
a_4=1 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
$$

Each output is equal to the number of rows long enough to reach it. Therefore, a value $a_k$ affects the first $a_k$ outputs.

---

## Algorithm description

First, initialize a vector of length $m$ called $b$, setting all elements to $0$. Next, for each element $a_i$ in $a$, increment $b_{a_i}$ by one. (this is the last element to be affected by $a_i$.)

Next, we will iterate backward over $b$, adding the next element and storing the result back into $b$. This effectively sums all higher elements in the old $b$.

## Pseudocode:

```
conjugate(array a, int n, int m)
  b = new Array length m (all zeros)

  for i = 1 to n
    b[a[i]] += 1

  for i = m-1 downto 1
    b[i] += b[i+1]

  return b
```

## Ruby Implementation

```
def conjugate(a)
  b = Array.new(a[0], 0)
  a.each do |x|
    b[x-1] += 1
  end
  (a[0]-2).downto 0 do |i|
    b[i] += b[i+1]
  end
  b
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7BCsMgEETv@Yo9RmJE20JOOfQ7xMMabZsetBglCeTfrRVaysAMw86DDUnvORt7g8m7Z7pjtC2SBkDDCNcQcGfOri1KrijwzwGZxekBxsOxHaWXqdx6oaAbQZRunSleif5EmPGrix54BeYvMNd5yU6oH6ObkvmV4vL3jBzoQC9VZyoUyW8)

## Efficiency

We have one loop over $a$ and one loop over $b$, giving $\Theta(n+m)$.

Comment: In the pseudo-code, shouldn't array b be of length m? And btw, m = a[0], right?

Comment: *(a[0] is the first element of a)

Comment: @VishalSharma Yes, the length of `b` should be `m` not `n`. If I can assume that m is equal to the first element of `a` then I can make this code a bit simpler... Let me do just that.